# which OS version do I have: Linux (rpm) or Linux (deb)?

Tags: package-management

I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS  64-bit.  I just bought a 4-1 printer Brother (MFC-J480DW) from Staples because I was told it was Linux compatible. It looks like it is, but to download the correct drivers it starts with this choice:  which OS version do I have,  Linux (rpm) or Linux (deb) ?   I studied up and now somewhat know what rpm and deb refer to, yet I’m clueless as to the choice in regard to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  Any clues?

Comment: Ubuntu is  debian based distro so choose Linux (deb).

Comment: As far as your printer, you could most likely use your printer with Ubuntu's built in support just by going to the printer section of `System Settings` (find it by clicking the gear icon in the top right of the screen.  The click `Add`.  You'll most likely find your printer in under the Network section.  Follow the prompt to install.

Comment: Since this is an ubuntu stackexchange the answer will always be .deb but for future reference in case you start using other distros here's a list of major distros grouped by family: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Linux_distributions, note Debian uses .deb, Red Hat (called RPM in the list) uses .rpm, Gentoo, Slackware, Arch etc uses variants of tar like .tbz or .tar.xz etc.

Answer (score 15):

You want `.deb`

Ubuntu is a distribution based on Debian Linux, and as such it is (typically) compatible with Debian packages which have names ending with `.deb`

Comment: I just want to chime in to say that Ubuntu no longer has *guaranteed* compatibility with Debian packages (since Ubuntu's underlying pieces and parts have changed too much)... but you're right that they often work!

Comment: And we shall not forget - although I want to - about snappy packages :)

Answer (score 3):

if you are using a descendant of Debian such as Ubuntu (or any derivative of Ubuntu such as Kali or Mint), then you have `.deb` packages. If you are using fedora, CentOS, RHEL and so on, then it is `.rpm`. If you want more detail on this, see [this Unix & Linux question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103531/whats-deb-and-rpm-and-how-is-it-different-from-msi).

Answer (score 0):

- Well Ubuntu is debian system (.deb) so you have to choose .deb
- If you were using fedora, then you would have chosen .rpm

Answer (score 0):

You need to select .deb. Ubuntu comes from Debian variants. This can help you https://www.wikivs.com/wiki/DEB_vs_RPM